# Using NicEdit with Knockout

Tags: knockout.js, tinymce, nicedit

I'm looking to create a custom Knockout binding for use with the WYSIWYG editor NicEdit http://nicedit.com/index.php . I found a fiddle example of what looked like a similar binding here for the TinyMCE library but haven't had any success in replicating for my needs.

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/GwkRQ/

Has anyone created a working custom binding for this before, or has anyone found any other work around for this? When the instance of the NicEditor is applied normally, it appears to update the value of the attached  accordingly but does not trigger the knockout observable update.

As an example, using the following javascript and html does not produce a valid result.

JS here

```
var viewModel = {
    content: ko.observable("<p>I want this text to load and change in the editor</p>"),
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
new nicEditor().panelInstance('testTextArea');
```

HTML here

```
<form method="post" action="somepage">
    <textarea id="testTextArea" name="content" style="width:100%" data-bind="value: content"></textarea>
</form>
```

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: As you mention, creating a custom binding is the way to go.  Share the code you created when you tried to create a NicEditor version of the custom binding, and we can help you figure out why it isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with the following custom binding which seems to work. I use a bit of JQuery, but not that much, so you can always replace it with something non-JQuery.

The custom binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.nicedit = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        var area = new nicEditor({fullPanel : true}).panelInstance(element.id, {hasPanel : true});
        $(element).text(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value)); 

        // function for updating the right element whenever something changes
        var textAreaContentElement = $($(element).prev()[0].childNodes[0]);
        var areachangefc = function() {
            value(textAreaContentElement.html());
        };

        // Make sure we update on both a text change, and when some HTML has been added/removed
        // (like for example a text being set to "bold")
        $(element).prev().keyup(areachangefc);
        $(element).prev().bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved', areachangefc);
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        var textAreaContentElement = $($(element).prev()[0].childNodes[0]);
        textAreaContentElement.html(value());
    }
};
```

And how to use it:

```
<textarea id="area1" data-bind="nicedit: title" style="width: 640px"></textarea>
```

... where in my example "title" is your bound property of course.

There are two "limitations":

- The textarea must have a DOM "id" attribute otherwise it crashes.
- With IE (at least, version 8) the `DOMNodeInserted` and `DOMNodeRemoved` are not fired, which means that you have to type something after modifying the style of your text for it to be properly updated in your observable object.

Comment: This works great aside from the noted limitations. Probably going to try expanding it to take in the config as another binding to allow more flexability.

Comment: This almost works perfectly but for some reason the text cursor keeps jumping to the start of the editor :/

Comment: I've added a JSFiddle to show this issue : http://jsfiddle.net/swkbt68h/1/

Comment: I've found another version of the binding that works well:
https://gist.github.com/docnoe/7cb90c1c3e6ddea5e37f/

None the less you would not believe how happy I am to find this question.  I spent about 8 hours trying various editors yesterday, about 15 variants of TinyMCE bindings, CKEDitor, Trumbowyg but to name a few and each just completely failed to work.  Seriously I want to hug you guys right now!